# Ограничение при редактировании, когда не хватает репутации для самостоятельной правки

Tags: поддержка, предлагаемые-правки

Если в вопросе код не отформатирован должным образом, при редактировании вопроса, по сути добавляем два символа (обратные кавычки), но этого недостаточно, чтобы предложить правку, т.к. нужно минимум 6 символов.

Что делать в таком случае, как обойти это ограничение, или в данном случае нужно просто оставить все как есть, без внесения правок?

Answer (score 4):

Я думаю, стоит обратить внимание на текст, который выводится при попытке отправить на проверку такую правку. Он гласит следующее:

> [image: Правка должна быть не менее 6 символов; может быть в сообщении можно исправить или улучшить что-нибудь ещё?]

Т.о. стоит попробовать улучшить сообщение ещё и в каком-то другом аспекте. Может быть даже проявить какую-то изобретательность (например, добавив скрытые комментарии в правку, правда ревьюверы могут отнестись к такому совершенно по-разному). Хотя, конечно, я соглашусь, что размер изменений (в символах) не всегда отражает качество правки. Но, к сожалению, автоматизированно проверить качество невозможно, поэтому идут на такие меры по ограничению минимальной длины правки для участников с недостаточной для выполнение единоличной правки репутацией ([2К репы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)), чтобы не забивать очередь проверки и не отвлекать ревьюверов от чего-то более серьёзного (ведь у ревьюверов тоже есть суточное ограничение по кол-ву проверок).

Для любителей порядка (а ведь правки для этого и сделаны) это своего рода стимул быстрее набрать необходимую репутацию, чтобы не зависеть от проверяющих.

Comment: ага,тоесть когда я набью 2к репы,эти ограничения пропадут? спасибо за ответ

Comment: @Riangry добавил ссылку на страницу привилегии.

Answer (score 3):

Два `` ` `` - это выделить один фрагмент inline-кода. Честно говоря, у меня вопрос, а точно ли такая правка нужна и заслуживает внимания? Конечно, могут быть случаи, когда она очень важна, например, если это html-разметка и парсер вообще сожрал её. Но в большинстве случаев скорее будет выделение одного слова, которое и так отличается - вопрос на русском, а код на английском. И вообще, выделением кода злоупотребляют.

О чём стоит задуматься?

- Может правка не нужна?
- Может нужен не inline-код, а блок кода? 4 пробела всё ещё мало (хотя если будет 2 строки, то уже 8), но можно добавить маркировку языка или использовать более новый блок кода из ```` ``` ````.
- Inline-код можно выделять не только одной `` ` ``, но и несколькими, например ```` ```code``` ```` превратится в `code` - это уже 6 символов, чего достаточно для правки (теоретически, может там есть какие-то ещё валидации - минимальные 30 символов на ответ так не накручиваются, хотя на комментарий можно).

Ну и как только будет достаточно репутации, чтобы правки не попадали в очередь проверок, можно будет делать правки любого размера без ограничения на 6 символов.